# delete image using msg_id in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a camera whose picture is achieve using the IP address of the camera in the web browser.

I can download the image link then and then download the image to my local system.

After that, I have to delete the image using msg_id, token, parameter.

I added the image link for delete using msg_id.

```
from time import sleep
import os  
import sys
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import piexif
import os
from fractions import Fraction

archive_url = "http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/"

def get_img_links(): 

    # create response object 
    r = requests.get(archive_url) 

    # create beautiful-soup object 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib') 

    # find all links on web-page 
    links = soup.findAll('a') 

    # filter the link sending with .mp4 
    img_links = [archive_url + link['href'] for link in links if link['href'].endswith('JPG')] 

    return img_links  

def FileDelete():

    FilesToProcess =  get_img_links()
    print(FilesToProcess)
    FilesToProcessStr = "\n".join(FilesToProcess)
    for FileTP in FilesToProcess:

        tosend = '{"msg_id":1281,"token":%s,"param":"%s"}' %(token, FileTP)
        print("Delete successfully")
```

Getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'token' is not defined


runfile('D:/EdallSystem/socket_pro/pic/hy/support.py', wdir='D:/EdallSystem/socket_pro/pic/hy')
['http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13063800.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13064200.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13064600.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13065000.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13065400.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13065800.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13072700.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13073100.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13073500.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13073900.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13074300.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13074700.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13075100.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13075500.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13075900.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13080300.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13080700.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13081100.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13081500.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13081900.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13082300.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13082700.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13083100.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13083500.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13083900.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13084300.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13084700.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13085100.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13085500.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13085900.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13090300.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13090700.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13091100.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13091500.JPG', 'http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191123000/13091900.JPG']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\EdallSystem\socket_pro\pic\hy\support.py", line 82, in <module>
    FileDelete()

  File "D:\EdallSystem\socket_pro\pic\hy\support.py", line 74, in FileDelete
    tosend = '{"msg_id":1281,"token":%s,"param":"%s"}' %( FileTP)

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't define `token` in the `FileDelete` function. Therefore then you try to use it in `tosend = '{"msg_id":1281,"token":%s,"param":"%s"}' %(token, FileTP)`, you get an error

Comment: error shows `%( FileTP)` but you shows code with `%(token, FileTP)` - it seems you run different code then you show in question.

Comment: @EyalGolan can you write a code for delete the image in SD card using this MSGID.